# Should I import a weak framework?

Tags: frameworks, mapkit, tvos, apple-tv

I have a framework that needs the Apple `MapKit` framework. I want to be sure that this framework is usable even on machine where `MapKit` is not available (aka AppleTV). Is it safe to use

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

or should I use only reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, there is no MapKit on tvOS, thus not even the headers are present. I have split my (huge) support framework into a bunch of nicely separated individual frameworks. Everything that depends on MapKit is in a dedicated framework, which does not get included nor linked for my tvOS build. In my opinion, this works best.